# What is the angle that $\overline{OQ}$ has now been rotated through?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

Information you need:
*A wheel of radius 10 cm rests against a step 5 cm high as shown. the wheel is rotated about Q by pushing until its center O is directly above Q. What is the angle $\overline{OQ}$ has now been rotated through?*

Comment: Welcome to Math.stackexchange. You should edit your question to include your thoughts on the exercise, what you understand about it or what you do not understand about it. Include what attempts you have made to solve it and what obstacles you encountered. Questions of the sort "Please work this exercise for me" are generally not well received and are downvoted or closed.

Comment: What is the current angle and what is the final angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the origin of the coordinate system at the point $O$, then you want to find $Q$ on the left of $O$ that will be at $y = -5$.  The equation of the wheel is

$ x^2 + y^2 = 100 $

So at $y = -5$, we have $ x = - \sqrt{75} $  (it has to be negative because we're taking the point on the left of the center).

Using the $\text{Atan2}$ , we can find the angle from the positive $x$ direction that $OQ$ makes

$\theta_1 = \text{Atan2}( - \sqrt{75}, -5 ) = \pi + \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3} } \right) = \dfrac{7 \pi}{6} $

Therefore, the vector $\vec{QO}$ makes an angle of

$ \theta_2 = \pi - \left(2 \pi - \dfrac{7 \pi}{6} \right) = \dfrac{\pi}{6} $

with the positive $x$ axis.

And we want to rotate $\vec{QO}$ till it makes an angle $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ with the positive $x$ axis.

Hence, the angle that $\overline{OQ}$ has been rotated through is

$ \theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2} - \dfrac{\pi}{6} = \dfrac{\pi}{3} $